# Custom server script

Tags: c#, .net

I have built a small HTTP server based on the HTTPListener class.

What I would like to know is, is there any scripting language I can put in my HTML files that can be natively executed in C#?

Something similar to how PHP works when it is mixed with HTML code.

lee

Answer (score 1):

You could use any of the available templating engines for .NET such as WebForms, Razor, ...

Comment: Thanks. I took a quick look at those. But It is not clear if I can include them with a stand alone .NET Winform app. All the instructions seem to be targeted at asp.net. I was hoping to find something simple. Perhaps extracting script from the HTML file and running it as if it were C# code. Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: It's trivial to build a web server using the HttpListener class and the WebForm view engine. Take a look here: http://www.codingvision.net/networking/c-http-server-with-asp-net/

Comment: Thanks Darin. Just to make sure I am not missing anything; This solution is meant to work in a WinForm app, not ASP, right?

Comment: No, this solution is not specifically meant for WinForms. This solution could work in any type of application (including WinForms). You could host the HttpListener even in a console application if you want.

Comment: Thanks. That is a great lead. I am trying this now, however, the app does not seem to want to find my files. Is there some default location on my filesystem for the HTML files?

Comment: There's no default location. You are specifying the root location of the ApplicationHost as third parameter to the `ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost` method. In the article I have linked to, the author used `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` which means that the files are expected to be located in the same folder as your executable. But remember that if you want to host ASP.NET you need to have the assemblies in a subfolder called `bin`.

Comment: I created the bin. I had the same thought about the location of the files, but it is not finding them. Don't suppose you could venture a guess as to what could be throwing it off.

Answer (score 1):

There is one you can use: T4.

If you want to have templated defined at runtime, you will need a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating to be present, you can learn how to use it pragmatically from the article [Processing Text Templates by using a Custom Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126519.aspx) (at msdn).

From the article:

> To execute a text template, you call the ProcessTemplate method of
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine:
>
> ```
> using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating;
> ...
> Engine engine = new Engine();
> string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(templateString, host);
> ```
>
> In the host parameter, you must provide a class that implements
>   ITextTemplatingEngineHost. This is called back by the Engine.

By this method you can have make your program read the template from a file or load it from a resource.

The article [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Text Template Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126579.aspx) (also at msdn) will help you to implement the interface ITextTemplatingEngineHost.

---

As an alternative, if you will have fixed templates defined beforehand, you can create the tt files and use the following method:

```
TestTemplate testTemplate = new TestTemplate();
string output = testTemplate.TransformText();
```

Where TestTemplate is a class generated by VisualStudio from a TestTemplate.tt file. Using this method the template is fixed at compile time. So you will not be able to define it at runtime, from example by reading it from a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simple I recommend you to take a look at T4 templates. You can start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) and [here](http://www.goatly.net/2010/11/19/using-t4-to-generate-content-at-runtime.aspx)